# Something not quite right with the flag help message

Tags: discussion, user-interface, flags

When you flag for moderator attention, this is what is shown in the box for free-form flags:

> Something not quite right? Let us know about it, and please provide relevant links if possible.

So, ok, the purpose of flagging is described in the [flag posts privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts), which a user will have been told about once (and probably won't have read). But the text in the flagging interface itself is not only uninformative, it's downright misleading.

I don't have wording to offer yet, but here are things we should convey at least indirectly:

- Flagging is [not for getting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120519/disallow-low-rep-users-from-flagging-for-moderator-attention-with-a-custom-messa) to your questions.
- Flagging is not for signaling incorrect answers.
- Flagging is not for general help with the site, for feedback about how the site works or for complaints about closures (that's what Meta is for).
- Flagging is for signaling abusive behavior.
- Flagging is for getting immediate assistance with a specific site issue, for example merging accounts (or can users now do this on their own?).
- Flagging is for requesting the reopening of a closed question after it's been edited.

Comment: I like the wording a mod used when declined one of my flags: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"...

Comment: @YannisRizos That's one of the canned messages

Comment: Yep I didn't really assume it was written for me :) Still I like the wording, and I think it could make it into the message...

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm primarily thinking of newbies who have no idea what requires moderator intervention.

Comment: Well newbies that failed to read the flag privilege page will probably fail to read the textarea help message as well...

Answer (score 1):

How are you going to stuff all of that into a box that's 5 inches wide and 1/2 inch tall?

People learn by doing, and you get them to *do* by making the interface friendly; hence the current wording. If they're doing it wrong, they're going to find out real quick.

Note that the tooltip text for the `flag` link includes the words: *"Flag this post for serious problems."*

I haven't seen a flood of bad flags by new users.  They do occur, but not that often, not often enough to justify a change in the wording, IMO.

Comment: Make it bigger!

Comment: I'm not proposing to fit all this into a box. There should be a one or two-sentence summary. I don't have one to offer, so I'm just throwing ideas around. The current wording is misleading, and you neglected the part of the tooltip that says “or moderator attention”. Is a lack of answers to my question grounds for flagging? A wrong answer? I haven't seen a flood of bad flags either, but [apparently casperOne has](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120519); the flag help message is misleading anyhow.

Comment: You presume that the rest of us know of some way to magically fit all of those bullet points into two short sentences that people will read.

Comment: Robert, I think you could cover 80% of the problem with one sentence: `Do not flag content simply for being incorrect`

Comment: What does "incorrect" mean to a new user?

Comment: @Robert - my original comment failed to consider flagging for things like merging and such.  I think adding a sentence for what **not** to flag for (like above) would go a long way

Comment: @Robert - hmm, not sure.  Maybe this is one of those things that seems easy but is difficult to implement

Answer (score 1):

Are we really seeing a *problem* with the free-form moderator flags?

I am open to improving the text (though your post offers no such improvement suggestions..) but I am not totally convinced there is an actual problem here to be fixed.

Generally speaking, having to enter text of *some* kind makes these flags friction-y enough that we don't get a lot of bogus ones. At least, I don't recall any moderator ever mentioning custom message mod flags as a specific problem.

Comment: [This is the complaint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120519/disallow-low-rep-users-from-flagging-for-moderator-attention-with-a-custom-messa). I disagree with the request, but I do find the current wording misleading, it does seem to imply that “my question isn't getting enough attention” is a valid flag.

Comment: Its harder to tell now, since we are corralled into dismissing flags as "helpful", so many which are just not really helpful but that we don't want to take the time dealing with are lumped in with the ones that are good but not worth taking mod action over.  If I had to guess, maybe about 5-10% of these flags are flat out wrong.  The request would be helpful, but at this point who knows if it would reduce the overall number of bad flags.  Perhaps it would help on the "why was my flag dismissed as unhelpful" side...

Comment: @won wrong as in "technically incorrect, but there was still a problem with the post" or wrong as in "this question, its answers, and all the comments are perfect in every way, man!". I almost never see the latter.. it does happen, but like 1/100 flags. I subscribe to the where there is smoke (flags) there is fire (problems with the question, answers, or comments) philosophy, and it's what I see almost all the time when I handle flags.